# Unique of email address validation (xpages)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Case: Create a database (system) for a user to request for an email and update in names.nsf.

Problem found, let say we can't edit names.nsf view or create a new view just to check the uniqueness of Internet address.

sample: InternetAddress (Email address) field of a user is: TestUser1@brooke.com.my

I can't use picker validator just to validate the uniqueness of email address as there has no view and not allow to create a view in names.nsf just to sort it and use it for validation, May I know got another way to do validation~?

Sample value inside arr

[image: array]

New Coding Added on 19/07/2017

```
var setdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("System Setting", "");
var server = setdoc.getItemValueString("DBSvr");
var DName = setdoc.getItemValueString("DbPath");
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(server, DName, false);

var vw:NotesView = db.getView("($VIMPeopleByLastName)")
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument();

var arr = [];       

while (doc != null) {
    var tmpdoc = vw.getNextDocument(doc);
    arr.push(doc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress"));
    doc.recycle();  //  to prevent IBM Notes Crash use recycle  //  The recycle method unconditionally destroys an object // and returns its memory to the system.
    doc = tmpdoc;
}

value=getComponent("mail11").getValue() +"@devsvr1.pcs.com.my"

return @IsMember(value, arr);
```

[image: Error]

Newer Testing result:

[image]

-property of the field

[image]

-validation property field

[image]

-Coding part

```
<xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var setdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("System Setting", "");
var server = setdoc.getItemValueString("DBSvr");
var DName = setdoc.getItemValueString("DbPath");
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(server, DName, false);

var vw:NotesView = db.getView("($VIMPeopleByLastName)")
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument();

var arr = [];       

while (doc != null) {
    var tmpdoc = vw.getNextDocument(doc);

        arr.push(doc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress"));

    doc.recycle();
    doc = tmpdoc;
}

value=getComponent("mail11").getValue() +"@devsvr1.pcs.com.my"

return @IsMember(value, arr);
}]]></xp:this.expression>
```

Comment: A shame they won't allow addition of a view to names.nsf because a (People By Email) view would make this simpler and not break anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I see three possibilities to look for internet addresses without changing names.nsf:

1. "Walk" through hidden view "($Users)" and compare your internet addresses with column `InternetAddress`
2. Use [database.search()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Database_search.html)
3. Use [database.FTSearch()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Database_FTSearch.html) if names.nsf is full-text indexed

Example for `search`:

```js
var formula = 'InternetAddress="TestUser1@brooke.com.my":"TestUser2@brooke.com.my";
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(formula);
if (dc.getCount() > 0) {
   // read documents' InternetAddresses and tell user which are used already
}
```

Example for `FTsearch`:

```js
var search = '[InternetAddress]="TestUser1@brooke.com.my";
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.FTsearch(search);
if (dc.getCount() > 0) {
   // tell user internet address is used already
}
```

Put your code into e.g. expression validator:

```xml
<xp:inputText
    id="inputMail1">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateExpression
            message="Your Error message">
            <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                ... your code ...
                return @IsMember(value, arr);
            }]]></xp:this.expression>
        </xp:validateExpression>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
<xp:message
    id="message1"
    for="inputMail1">
</xp:message>
```

`value` contains field's value to validate. Don't forget a message control to show error message to user.

Comment: I want to put within validation to check whether existed or not....which validator type is better to be used. As i try not success at all~

Comment: You could do a GetDocumentByKey in the ($NamesFieldLookup) or in the ($Users) view, using the address as lookup key.

Comment: if give Expression is invalid~ i will update my photo of error and new code

Comment: I try computed field my coding look ok. it give "true" , means existing. But in validator - expression, it give an error message  Expression is invalid

Comment: `true` means in your case that email already exist. Set `message="Sorry, but this login name already exists"`. **Don't** set "required field" -
 delete `required="true"`.

Comment: Put your code into "expression" (= Server Side JavaScript SSJS), **not** "clientScript" (= Client Side JavaScript CSJS)

Comment: After test it, It still give me same error! Expression is invalid!

Comment: Take my expression validator code, return a false and later a true, look how it works and then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **SSJS** function which checks if a user with a certain **ID** exists in any of the available address books:

```
function isDominoUser(id) {
    try {
        var db,vw,doc,itr;

        itr=sessionAsSigner.getAddressBooks().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            db=itr.next();
            try {
                if (!db.open()) continue;
                vw=db.getView("($Users)");
                doc=vw.getDocumentByKey(id,true);
                if (doc) {
                    doc.recycle();
                    vw.recycle();
                    return true;
                }
                vw.recycle();
            } catch(err1) {}
        }

    } catch(err) {
        java.lang.System.out.println("ERROR: "+err.toString()+" [isDominoUser]");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since the **($Users)** view also contains the mail addresses you can use the function to find out if a user has already been registered with a certain address.

Based on the code sample you posted, your validation expression would then look like this:

```
return isDominoUser(getComponent("mail11").getValue()+"@devsvr1.pcs.com.my");
```

PS: You have to make sure that the signer at least has read access to the address books.

Comment: Question: Do i need to post it on "Expression" or "Client Script" Area?

Comment: Btw: My answer is based on what you wanted to achieve with the code you initially posted. However, if you intend to show the error message if the user already exists you of course have to use the negated version, i.e. `return !isDominoUser(...)`.